# Domain types in Spring MVC controller method signatures not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

After updating Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE to 2.3.1.RELEASE, domian class conversion stopped working inside controller methods.

Here is the reference controller, which was working perfectly fine till Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/users")
class UserController {

  @RequestMapping("/{id}")
  String showUserForm(@PathVariable("id") User user, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "userForm";
  }
}
```

in 2.3.1.RELEASE, I get the below error, when i make the following request

```
GET /users/<userid>
```

> 2020-06-17 13:07:12.780  WARN 574637 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.xxx.User'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.xxx.User': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Comment: Where is Post parameter

Comment: fixed the logs, sorry for the wrong logs earlier

Comment: What are you sending the in the string for the value can you put that in the question too?

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1743

Comment: It seems a same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62483532/4506703), caused by a bug of Spring Data Commons: - [Translation of URI segments and request parameters into aggregates broken](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1743) This bug affects Spring Boot version 2.3.1, 2.2.8 and 2.1.15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update to Spring Boot 2.3.2 which was [released "yesterday"](https://spring.io/blog/2020/07/24/spring-boot-2-3-2-available-now). This should fix your issue.

It contains the update to [Spring Data Neumann-SR2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.3.2.RELEASE). This version is listed a fix version for your [related bug ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1743).